# Php Slim Framework nested routes

Tags: php, routes, slim

i try something like:

```
    $app = new Slim();

    $app->get("/home", function() use($app) {

       //some query for sub pages
       $my_sub_page = 'subpage';

       $app->get("/home/" . $my_sub_page, function() use($app) {

           //

       });

});
```

but the result of `www.site.com/home/subpage` is 404...
is possible to do something like this?
I miss something?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you nesting the definitions? It doesn't seem like it adds any value/functionality than doing it directly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use [route parameters](http://docs.slimframework.com/pages/routing-parameters/):

```
$app->get("/home/:mysubpage", function($mysubpage) use($app) {
    //do something with $mysubpage
    //it contains the value of www.site.com/home/{whatever-you-put-here}
});
```

This helps you to get dynamic routes with arbitrary arguments.

Answer (score 15):

Use http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Groups

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

// API group
$app->group('/api', function () use ($app) {

    // Library group
    $app->group('/library', function () use ($app) {

        // Get book with ID
        $app->get('/books/:id', function ($id) {

        });

        // Update book with ID
        $app->put('/books/:id', function ($id) {

        });

        // Delete book with ID
        $app->delete('/books/:id', function ($id) {

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: The link refers to the V2 documentation, so here's the link to the [new V3 documentation about route groups](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-groups) as an addition.